# Weird HTML Issue

Tags: html, css

This is probably a simple issue but...

How can I get the image to fill the empty space on the right of the text? Screenshot: http://awesomescreenshot.com/076a3d871

The HTML file is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22089670/paywallify/index.html
CSS: dl.dropbox.com/u/22089670/paywallify/css/style.css

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure the main box has a width (which you have), then reduce the width of the intro-box. set float: left;

make sure the aside box has a width that fits between main width minus intro-box width and set float:right;

Comment: For some reason, there is this huge white space in firefox http://awesomescreenshot.com/017a3kl3f but not in chrome. Would you happen to know why? https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22089670/paywallify/index.html

Comment: Chrome isn't showing the iframe with the form + green button. Firefox is showing it. Looks like you'll have to change the height of that iFrame (not to 100% like now, but just the actual height in pixels)

Comment: On chrome it loads perfectly (no space between green button and "By clicking...") https://dl.dropbox.com/u/22089670/paywallify/chrome.JPG but on firefox there is this weird space in the same position (http://awesomescreenshot.com/017a3kl3f) and it's the same code. Could it be a discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: aha yes now I see. I didn't enable the blocked content :)
But there is a difference, chrome gives it a pixel height. Firefox just says height : 100% to the iframe holding the form.

What you have to do is give the frame a static pixel height. Or did you already do this?

Comment: No I haven't. So like this: <div class="intro-box" style="width:365px;height:450px;"> ?

Comment: No,

you're inserting this script in your main page: http://form.jotform.us/jsform/21911562954153 .

That's the script holding the iframe that displays the form with green button.

In that script, there's a line going like: var htmlCode = "<"+"iframe src=\"\" allowtranspar.......

There you'll see "style=\"width:100%; height:"+this.initialHeight+"px;"
-->set height static (like 150px or something and see if it works)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I set it at 1000px and at 20px and it was still the same. :/ Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the width of:

```
section#main .intro-box
```